# Comparing SSL Cipher Suite Notations

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, tls1.2

We have a client whose supported TLS 1.2 Cipher Suite is noted this format...

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
```

And we have the server (nginx I think?) whose supported list is in this notation...

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
```

The client cannot establish the connection, so I assume the client/server do not agree on a supported Cipher.  Any ideas how I can obtain a list of supported ciphers from the abbreviated server notation?

I know that EECDH is an alias for ECDHE, so I would have assumed one of these two ciphers would have matched.

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
```

Any ideas why not?

Comment: "The client cannot establish the connection, so I assume the client/server do not agree on a supported Cipher." What are the error messages? Note that you are kind of offtopic here as your question is not about programming. [sf] may be more relevant, but check the help section about what is on topic or not. PS: TLS cipher suites names are a mess, everyone does them differently... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openssl ciphers -V 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM'` gives you all the ciphers in OpenSSL notations. To translate this to the notation from the RFC see the mapping at the end of [man ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html). When doing this you  get the following shared ciphers which you already correctly identified:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

But, these are both ECDSA ciphers so they require the server to have an ECC certificate. I assume that in your case the server has only an RSA certificate (which is still more common) so that essentially there are no shared ciphers. Instead the client would need to offer these ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA384
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server is publicly available, head over to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and test your server for supported cipher suites. It will give you a list in the format you require.

If you server isn't public you can do the same thing with [testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh).